# Electron: Zurb Foundation Tabs not working

Tags: css, zurb-foundation, electron

I'm not sure why my tabs are not working, I think I've imported foundation files correctly, I'm not sure how to test how.

I tried the markup from the docs on both browser and electron app, but it only works on the browser.

Please help. Thank you.

Gist: https://gist.github.com/mamarilmanson/4c3d9ca52c3cc745ee1aff0269b53f9b

Comment: Did you check for errors in the DevTools console?

Comment: yes... and nothing is appearing...

Comment: Is this code in a repository I can access? Would help if I could run it.

Comment: I solved it... eventually I need to put the `$(document).foundation();` at the very end of the file being loaded to activate the tabs plugin... :D